# How to log db output in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

I am looking for a way to log not only query itself (like `select * from users where...`) but also result of the query.

for example:

I asked for `User` model in a query and I want to see what was returned from the database, something like: `{user_id: 30, email: 'email@example.com', name: 'whatever'}`.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in development environnment, this should do the job:

```
tail -f log/development.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Handy documentation is available in rails guides go through [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger)

but putting output in logs will make the log files go huge and will consume lots of space.

Word of caution: Avoid in Production